# How to delete added (not modified) lines between two files in BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed, compare, line

I have two .smali files that are the same but there are some added lines in the second file. I need to remove these lines in the second file (if they are equal to a very simple regex pattern) using bash

**file 1:**

```
# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method
```

**file 2:**

```
# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1
    
    const/4 v1, 0x0

    invoke-direct {p7}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V
    
    const/4 c1, 0x0

    return-void
.end method
```

My regex pattern is `const\/\d\sv\d,\s0x\d`, so:

- the line `const/4 v1, 0x0` is removed
- the line `const/4 c1, 0x0` is not removed (because of the "c")
- the line `invoke-direct {p7}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V` is not removed because p7 derive from p0 and it's not a new added line but an edited line

**output file I need:**

```
# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1

    invoke-direct {p7}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V
    
    const/4 c1, 0x0

    return-void
.end method
```

I tried something with `awk` and `sed`, which wasn't even close to what I intended. How can I do this?

Comment: `grep 'const/[[:digit:]][[:space:]]v[[:digit:]],[[:space:]]0x[[:digit:]]' yourfile -v` ?

Comment: What does file 1 have to do with your question?

Comment: By default, `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions  , and doesn't understand `\d`, `\s`, `\w` etc., which are Perl regular expressions.

Comment: `GNU sed` supports `\s` and `\w` but not `\d`

Comment: `grep 'const/[[:digit:]][[:space:]]v[[:digit:]],[[:space:]]0x[[:digit:]]' yourfile -v` only remove that line from the second file but I need to compare the first file and the second file, and the different lines between them must be removed if they match to the regex pattern.

Comment: Do you know about the `comm` utility? It may help you. Good luck.

Comment: @rmroot – 
You mean if a line `const/4 v1, 0x0` is in both files, it is not to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

If `file1` are almost the same, except that `file2` has some added lines, and these lines are not wanted in `file2`, the way to fix that at a Unix-like shell prompt is:

```
cp file1 file2
```

Now they are the same, except possibly for attributes outside of the file content, like ownership and modification time stamp.